# Multi-paxos instance

Tags: distributed, paxos

In wikipediahttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_(computer_science), the proposal number and the instance number is inconsistent.
Message flow: Multi-Paxos, steady-state
   |         X--------->|->|->|       |  |  Accept!(N,I+1,W)
Message flow: Collapsed Multi-Paxos, steady state
   |         X->|->|  Accept!(N+1,I,W)

one is increment on instance number, one is ballot number, why?

Answer (score 2):

Nice catch, the following is what *should* happen:

- at the Start phase of the Multi-Paxos protocol, a Promise message is sent: here you increase the ballot number N with 1;
- at the Steady phase of the Multi-Paxos protocol, a Accept message is sent: here you increase the instance number I with 1.

Thus, the correct answer for would be Accept(N,I+1,W) for both Multi-Paxos and Collapsed Multi-Paxos steady state.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I don't agree with your modification on Wikipedia. The instance number I is the Ith law in the ledger. It should increase by 1 when the Ith instance is closed. The ballot number N should unique in the same instance. So, i think the answer should be Accept!(N,I+1,W) or Accept!(N+1,I+1,W).